# $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$E_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:2x-y=0\}$, $E_2=\{(2x-y,0\:(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Show that $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^2$.

How am I supposed to sum the two. Do I have to sum them:

$a(x,2x)+b(2x-y,0)=0$, and prove $a=b=0$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show that $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^2$.

To show that $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the **direct sum** ("$\oplus$") of $E_1$ and $E_2$, you need two things:

- "*sum*": every element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as $e_1+e_2$ with $e_1 \in E_1$ and $e_2 \in E_2$;
- "*direct*": the intersection of $E_1$ and $E_2$ contains only the zero vector.

---

**Hint**: things become simpler when you realise that:

- $E_1$ consists of elements of the form $(x,2x)$;
- $E_2$ consists of elements of the form $(t,0)$.

Can you continue?

Comment: How do I prove the intersection is zero? How do I prove they are linearly independent?

Comment: @PedroGomes The intersection consists of the elements satisfying $(x,2x)=(t,0)$. From the second component it is clear that $2x=0 \iff x = 0$ but then also $t=0$, so only $(0,0)$ is in the intersection.

Comment: Do I need to prove they are linealry independent?

Comment: No: you need to show that any $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ can be written as the sum of elements from $E_1$ and $E_2$ (see my answer; first bullet).